# Проверка на правильность

Tags: javascript, функции

Привет, мне надо было сделать функцию, которая будет принимать любое кол-во чисел и возвращать их произведение. Если аргументы отсутствуют, возвращать 0. У меня такой код, это правильно?

```js
function multiply(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a * b * c);
    return 0;
} multiply();
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не правильно, так как:

1. функция всегда возвращает ноль, а должна возвращать ноль только если она была вызвана без аргументов (зато функция что-то выводит в консоль, хотя этого не требовалось...)
2. если не учитывать пункт (1), то функция работает только когда ей передали три аргумента.

   - Если передать меньшее число аргументов, переменные, отвечающие непереданным аргументам будут иметь значение `undefined`, что при умножении приведёт к `NaN`
   - Если передать большее число аргументов, то функция посчитает только произведение первых трёх, а должна была посчитать произведение всех...

---

1. Исправить пункт (1) можно убрав вывод в консоль и заменив его возвращением  посчитанного произведения
2. Исправить пункт (2) поможет объект [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), доступный внутри функции, который является массиво-подобными объектом, содержащим аргументы, переданные в функцию. Связанные с ним вещи:

   - [`arguments.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length) — число аргументов переданных в функцию
   - `arguments[i]` — `i`-ый аргумент (нумерация с нуля)

   Таким образом, можно проверить число переданных аргументов, если их не было, то вернуть ноль, а иначе с помощью [цикла](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) посчитать произведение и вернуть его

   (аналогично `arguments` можно использовать синтаксис [оставшихся параметров](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Rest_parameters))

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Можно параметром функции сделать массив